# Show-hidden-icons menu hidden behind taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

When I press the arrow button with the tooltip "Show hidden icons" the last row of icons shows up behind the taskbar such that you barely see the icons and you can barely click them. I can't believe that this is on purpose. But why doesn't fix Microsoft this issue? Is there a way to solve this?

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Ensure your system is fully patched and that the display driver is the latest (downloaded from the manufacturer's website if possible).

Comment: This does not sound like an issue caused by anything Microsoft did or didn't do.  I was unable to reproduce this issue on my VM.

Comment: @harrymc There was a Windows update available. After updating it works fine again. But interestingly I had this problem for a few weeks.

Comment: But the problem was solved? And why wasn't the update installed automatically?

Comment: @harrymc After the Update the problem was solved. And I don't know why the update didn't install automatically.

Comment: @harrymc LOL: The problem is back. Shall I provide a screenshot?

Comment: Is the task double-height? Try also to set it to smaller icons.

Comment: @harrymc: No, it's usual height. My screen resolution is 3840x2160 with 175% "change the size of text, apps, and other items". How would I set it to smaller icons?

Comment: Right-click the taskbar, choose Taskbar settings, set "Use small taskbar buttons" to On.

Comment: @harrymc: I did that but the problem remains. Even with those small taskbar buttons.

Comment: I am experiencing the same flaw and am using a 4k screen with DPI scaling as well. The problem seems to appear once a program (e.g. a game running in exclusive fullscreen mode) requests a different resolution (e.g. 1920x1080). Once the program exits, Windows will return to 4k but the tray icons will be displayed behind the taskbar. A restart does "fix" the problem, until it happens again...

Comment: @Betaminos Thx for the reply. That might be true. I'll keep an eye on it when it happens.

Comment: @Betaminos The 175% scaling is rather buggy still. Not sure exactly what causes it but I find that killing the explorer.exe process and starting it again fixes the systray position

Comment: I have a 4K display and have this same problem. Thanks for your suggestion to killer explorer.exe and restart it. The problem showing the hidden icons went away after I did this!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say you restarted your computer.  You could be one of those many users (me included) that didn't know shutdown does not shutdown the computer.  Microsoft has added a default "feature" since Win 8 called "fast startup" which can be disabled.  Enabled by default, it closes your apps and then shuts off like a form of hibernate so when you turn the computer back on, it loads up faster.  I find this feature a waste of time and causes more issues than it's worth.

I have seen some user's issues go away after an update because the computer finally restarted at that time.  Unfortunately there is no way to know for sure now unless you are certain you used the restart option.

This particular UI issue feels like something that would have been resolved by a restart.